# React Native Pause/Play GIF

Tags: react-native

I have an animated GIF that I would like to use in React Native. I have it embedded in my app and playing, but I would like the ability to pause/play the GIF based on an event.

Is there currently a way to do this in React Native? I understand I can do this by using an MP4 instead, but I would like to keep the GIF if possible because it allows me to use transparency.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @Nainal https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-controlled-gif works on android :D

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an alternative static image to show when pause is enabled, and hide the gif.

Answer (score 0):

closest i know would be to use `lottie-react-native`, get more deatils [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native).
its has many props to control the animations, info [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native#api).

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

GIF can never be paused .You Convert GIF file to MP4 file and MP4